# Why is there an some sort of seam on my model

Tags: modeling, sculpt-mode, seams

All related Photo link cuz I can't seem to post in here [Photo link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1wv9.jpg)
It's normal when I make it,

but when I sculpt there's this yellow marking here

and when I subdivide, it looks like there's overlap issue. but it's not shown in normal mode with no subdivision

What's going on?

Comment: the yellow is Face Sets, you can remove that (header menu in Sculpt mode > Face Sets > Face Set from Visible). As for the line in Solid mode, maybe inverted normals? Or inner faces, overlapping vertices...

Comment: Thank you! Igot rid of the yellow face and search inverted normal and it did the trick

Answer (score 0):

the yellow is *Face Sets*, you can remove that (header menu in *Sculpt* mode > *Face Sets > Face Set from Visible*). As for the line in *Solid* mode, they are inverted normals, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>